# GCD and Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to solve a problem where fetching data from `CoreData` executes earlier than retrieving data from Parse and saving it to `CoreData`. How do I implement a queue to perform fetching data From Parse earlier? Now when I launch the app the database is updated, but it is not shown in the `tableView`.

Retrieving data from `CoreData`:

```
func fetchFromCoreData() {

    do {
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

        medicines = results  as! [Medicine]
        print("FetchFromCoreData")
        tableViewMedicines.reloadData()

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

Fetching data From Parse:

```
func fetchFromParse() {

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Medicine", inManagedObjectContext: context)
    let query = PFQuery(className: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects! {

                if let  name = object["medicineName"] as? String,
                    amount = object["amountQuantity"] as? String,
                    time = object["time"] as? String
                {

                    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", name)
                    self.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

                    do{
                        let fetchedEntities = try self.context.executeFetchRequest(self.fetchRequest) as! [Medicine]
                        //save to  Core Data


                        if fetchedEntities.count <= 0 {
                            let medicine = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.context)
                            medicine.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
                            medicine.setValue(amount, forKey: "amount")
                            medicine.setValue(time, forKey: "time")

                        }

                    } catch let error as NSError{
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }

        }

            do {

                try self.context.save()
                print("Context.save")


            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
            self.fetchFromCoreData()



    }


}
```

I'm calling them in `viewWillAppear`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
        //fetching data from Parse

        fetchFromParse()
        fetchFromCoreData()

        tableViewMedicines.reloadData()

    } else {

        //fetching data from Core data
        fetchFromCoreData()
        logOutButton.enabled = false

    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my post. I'm calling them in viewWillAppear, but don't know is it a difference

Comment: I don't know how you would do it, but you might have to call the `fetchFromParse` method inside the `fetchFromCoreData` method so you get the data from parse first. You would test for a network connection, then get data from parse, else you would just get the data from disk.

Comment: It is probably because your 'findObjectsInBackground' callback is being exectuted at some point in the future; after you re-load your table data. A hint would be to re-think where you call `tableViewMedicines.reloadData()`.

Comment: I tried to put `reloadData( )` in some points, but it doesn't help. Is there a way to put those two fetching methods in `viewWillAppear` in some GCD ?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` makes a network call and only executes its block later on, asynchronously, once the network call completes. Your code executes in this order:

1. Call `fetchFromParse()`
2. In `fetchFromParse()`, call Parse. Parse goes off and talks to the network in the background...
3. Call `fetchFromCoreData()`
4. At some point later on, Parse gets a network response, and your block executes.

You should expect that async network calls will **always** take a long time, and that callbacks from network activity will **always** be delayed to some unknown time in the future. Meaning, you can't somehow move step 4 above earlier in the list.

GCD is not the answer here. You have to wait until the network activity finishes before you can process results from Parse. In the meantime, your app needs to be responsive, so you can't just sit around waiting for that to happen.

What you need to do is re-do the Core Data fetch after the Parse call completes. Reloading the table view isn't enough if you're still displaying the results of the earlier fetch.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the whole process. So you suggest putting the `fetchFromParse` after the `query` block in `fetchFromParse` ?  I have another strange problem, because when i put `tableView.reloadData()` in `fetchFromParse` it only show in the `tableView` one call from `CoreData`.

Comment: No, I suggest calling `fetchFromCoreData()` inside the block, not after it. The whole point is that the block won't execute until later on, and you need to re-do your fetch only after that happens. Also beware that you might not be on the main queue in the block, so you may need to use `dispatch_async` to have the Core Data and UI updates work correctly.